# hg: how do I push newly created branch back into central repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I cloned the centeral repository via

```
hg clone my_project my_project_1
```

then after switching to a newly created repo I marked as a new branch

```
hg branch v1
```

While inside the new clone I issued

```
hg ci -m "branch created"
```

but when I tried to push the changes back to the original repository I cloned from
I got this error:

```
abort: push creates new remote branches: v1!
```

How do I push the branch into the original repository? 
Am I doing the right thing by trying to push the branch into the original repo? I just want to have a centralized repository which would contain branches and from which I would be able to check out branches.
What's the best way to deal with this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: With distributed version control you (normally) check out everything, not just a branch. Also: "a centralized repository" is possible but every developer checking out the repository has a clone of the central repository.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It depends on the version of Mercurial that you're using.  The command used to be `hg push -f ...` or `hg push --force ...` to force the creation of a new branch in the remote repository (which is usually OK).

However, using `-f` also allows you to create new heads in the remote repository (usually **not** OK), so current versions of Mercurial (1.6 and above) have a `--new-branch` option to `hg push` that allows you to create a branch, but not create a new head, so the command is:

```
hg push --new-branch
```

You can also limit pushes to just the branch that you're working on with the `-b` flag, so:

```
hg push --new-branch -b v1
```

Comment: It looks like unlike git, you have to create a commit to be able to push: `hg ci -m "Creating a branch"`

Comment: @NoBugs In the question, the OP said that they already did that.